# Forecasting costs with forecast interval using past performance

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

I'm trying to adopt a model for project cost forecasting in agile.

Consider the following table of previous costs per sprint, along with story points completed:

```
SP     Cost   Cost/SP
 1   $4,632    $4,632 
24   $1,128       $47 
 6   $2,680      $447
```

The average of Cost/SP across 3 sprints is \$1709 but (Total Cost)/(Total SP) is \$272. How do I name each of these averages ('sprint average', 'project average')?

If I need to forecast the cost of the remaining 50SP with a forecast interval, what do I do? Using sprints, the average is \$1709, std deviation is \$1270, 68% confidence is \$21,466 - \$149,386 which is a bit extreme. Something close to $272 * 50 (\$13,600) makes more sense, but how to get a forecast interval for this?

Comment: The reason the numbers are so volatile is because the majority of work was in sprint 1, but stories not verified done until sprint 2.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a Lean/Economics question and not a statistics question.  Are you sure this is stats related?

Comment: @EngrStudent Yes I know but it seemed to fit the "what's a good stats question" criteria, after all it is an averaging and 'confidence interval' calculation question

Comment: Am I correct that you are interested in forecast interval ([tag:prediction-interval]) rather than [tag:confidence-interval]? Check the tag descriptions to find out the difference.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes, you are correct, that was a term I picked up from project management articles